# How can i change the superclass value in subclass

Tags: swift

I have a custom class that named class a that look like this

```
Class A {
    var isTrue: Bool = true
    if isTrue {
        print(“true”)
    else {
        print (“false”)
}
```

this is the first class (class A) that called as super class

```
Class B: A {
    Var isTrue = false
}
```

this is the class B that inherit class A. All i want is i change the value isTrue in class A from class B. so if i set the istrue to false, the variable isTrue in class A has changed to false.
i already look around stackoverflow, that many of the naswer suggested for using init on class A and override the init on class B, but i think i cant do that because in my project class A got inherited by many classes, and i just want to make a condition for 1 or 2 classes

Comment: I think you should read more about how inheritance works, the only way to achieve the desired result is to use static variables. In this case, you will have to operate on a "type" level rather than "instance" level.

Comment: so its better to use struct ? i already tried to use override isTrue: Bool { return false } in class B. But i want to reset the value of isTrue in class B to true again in viewDidDisappear. i want to set isTrue = true, but it gices compiled error

Comment: @JordanHendo if you create an instance of `class A` and an instance of `class B`, the two instances are `NOT THE SAME`. You can only change the value of each instance separately

Comment: I'd agree with @SylvanDAsh, maybe you could provide a better explanation with a real-world example so we could help you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, you want to override the initial value_ of `B.isTrue` to be `false`. You can override the initialiser to achieve this.

```
class B : A {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        isTrue = false
    }
}
```

Comment: override the istrue variable from class A using variable istrue in class b

Comment: @JordanHendo What do you mean by that exactly? You just want `B().isTrue` to be false, right? Then my answer should work.